# Export Google Plus1 without web scraping

Tags: google, google-plus-1

If I'm going to use it, I want to know I can get my entries out. While I can get my entries from my profile page, that only shows some at a time. If I had hundreds that could get tedious. Is there a better way?

Edit 7/8/2011: This Google Plus1 (+1), not Google+. Some answers were based on Google+ after another person edited this.

Comment: Sorry about the edit. Was using Google +1 and it didn't seem to be the same kind of data exportable as you would have in Google+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the [data liberation](https://plus.google.com/u/0/settings/exportdata) page (your name in the upper right -> `Account settings` -> `Data Liberation`). There you have the ability to export all data (you can even choose what data to get).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That link gives me Google+, which I wasn't invited to. I'm not seeing the equivalent path for Data Liberation under the regular Account settings.

Comment: Haven't you asked about your data *after* you signed up for Google+? This will work that way. For most other Google projects you can find instructions at http://www.dataliberation.org/

Comment: That now lists +1's as a choice. Haven't gotten it to work, though.

Comment: Got it to work. The estimate shows 1 file, 165B. But the actual .zip file is larger an appears correct.

Comment: More details: http://www.ampercent.com/download-google-plus-one-pages-posts-status-updates/9557/